# My wordpress the_content is giving me trash characters "Â£45", not sure where to check for encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I'm picking up trash characters whenever I use a £ symbol, I'm assuming something is wrong with my encoding.

I'm already using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I have `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in my apache2.conf

Oh yea and I'm doing some filtering on `the_content` but I've applied this:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

I should also state that this doesn't happen locally.

Is there anywhere else I need to declare encoding?

Comment: Fetching from database?

Comment: @DamienPirsy yup, is there some encoding to be done there?

Comment: Whats your SQL table charset?

Comment: @Jono20201 I see "latin1_swedish_ci" I don't think that's right, how do I change it. I just ran this on all tables but it didn't work: `ALTER TABLE myTable CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: @Jono20201 obviously I used my actual table name.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE abc DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` for your tables, then I think you need to alter every 'property' (can't think of proper name right now).

`ALTER TABLE abc CHANGE name name VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;`

Comment: @Jono20201 aha, thank you very much, I just came across `alter table` and `alter database` didn't come across the `VARCHAR` bit though :) is it necessary?

Comment: @UzumakiDev To be honest, I am not sure. I am not SQL pro, I can just about manage select, update, delete and insert but table editing/creating is the job of PhpMyAdmin for me - Laravel spoils me :). I edited my answer also.... But from a logical stand point, I dont think it would be needed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have come across this issue I ended up doing:

```
$str = str_replace("£", "&pound;", $str);
```

I'm sure this isn't the best way to do it, though.

**Edit:** Make sure your database is set to utf8_general_ci

Comment: :) this shall be the last resort.